# Verify two columns of two different tables match exactly

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select

When writing views and nesting views within deeper views I sometimes miss something and end up losing rows/data.  How can I check that columns from two different tables have an exact match of data?

Example:

```
select count(distinct table1.col1)
  from table1
 where table1.col1 not in (select distinct table2.col1 
                             from table2);
```

This would return the number of values in table1.col1 that are not in table2.  However, I don't know that this is a good solution as it doesn't count the table2.col1 values that do not exist in table1.col1.

Comment: Of course nesting views is generally a bad thing (At least in SQL Server). It may seem fine in development, but once you go to prod and have a lot of records, you can bring down the system by nesting views. I'd test those nested views by adding a fwew million test records to the base tables.

Comment: indeed, I would eventually rewrite the queries, creating a string of nested views is for proof of concept in the beginning to verify that the data is shaped the way I want it.  I would refactor the views when the database is rolled out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT MAX(x.t1_missing_count) AS t1_missing_count, 
       MAX(x.t2_missing_count) AS t2_missing_count
  FROM (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.col1) AS t1_missing_count,
       NULL AS t2_missing_count
  FROM TABLE_1 t1
 WHERE t1.col1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT t2.col1 
                         FROM TABLE_2 t2)
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,
       COUNT(DISTINCT t2.col1),           
  FROM TABLE_2 t2
 WHERE t2.col1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT t1.col1 
                         FROM TABLE_1 t1)) x
```

Comment: not sure why i didn't think to use a UNION.  So I take it using a NOT IN clause sub query is ok for an operation like this?

Comment: @galford13x: I don't have info on which of the three - NOT EXISTS, NOT IN, and LEFT JOIN/IS NULL - is the most efficient to use at this time.

Answer (score 6):

You can use two `EXCEPT` queries (or union them) to check:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1
FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT col1
FROM table2
```

That will show values that exist in table1, but not table2. Then run again with table names flipped for the opposite.

Comment: I like the simplicity.  I wrap this with a SELECT count() to get the number of differences.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) from (

select
table1.col1 from table1 left join table2 on table1.col1 = table2.col2
where table2.col1 is null

union

select table2.col1 from table2 left join table 1 on table2.col1 = table1.col1
where table1.col1 is null

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @count int, @count2 int


select @count = count(distinct table1.col1)
  from table1
 where table1.col1 not in (select distinct table2.col1 
                             from table2)

select @count2 = count(distinct table2.col1)
  from table2
 where table2.col1 not in (select distinct table1.col1 
                             from table1)

select @count + @count2
```

Comment: Using SQLite, can I use internal variables like MS SQL or MySQL?

Comment: I don't think it was re-tagged, but it is tagged SQL :)